# Is it "First thought of" or "Thought of first"?

Tags: grammar, questions, adjective-position

I came across a social media caption in which it says "This is what he thought of first". I want to ask if this is correct because what I have seen and think the correct way to say it is "This is what he first thought of". OR they are both correct and the position of 'first' doesn't matter so they mean the same thing or the position of 'first' matters and mean different thing.
Thanking you,
Guri

Comment: While your question is valid, do you believe tht social media captions are models of good language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is what he thought of first** is preferable, because the other sentence has a dangling preposition.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: It might be stricter in Greek or Latin, but in English, dangling prepositions aren’t always looked down *upon*.